# external Iomega Desktop USB Hard drive disconnects while in use

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, connection

I got an annoying problem with my external Iomega Desktop USB hard drive.

The entire hard drive is encrypted via TrueCrypt. So I am mounting the drive via TrueCrypt after connecting it to USB. That works fine for a couple of hours and I can access my data, e.g. I can use WinAmp to listen to my music stored on the drive. However, suddenly WinAmp stops playing and the drive is dismounted from TrueCrypt. Additionally, "USB Safety Removal" doesn't list the hard drive anymore. It's obviously disconnected from the computer. It's not turned off, though. Switching the drive off and on brings it back and I can mount it again. That happens totally randomly. Sometimes it doesn't happen the entire day but I've also recognized it about 3 times a day (with couple of hours in between).

Some facts about the environment:

- I am running *Windows 7 Professional 64-bit*
- the hard drive is a *[Iomega Desktop USB 1.5 TB external hard drive](http://go.iomega.com/en/products/external-hard-drive-desktop/prestige-amp-professional-desktop-series/prestige/?partner=4705#tech_specsItem_tab)*
- USB 2 drivers are in place
- USB selective suspend is turned off
- computer's power options are set to maximum power
- might be interesting: I bought the hard drive in the US and use it in Europe now

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a common problem me and a couple of other people had the same problem,

This is my Amazon review after buying it

> purchased this drive from Amazon in January 2008, but by the beginning of June I was getting random disconnects and reconnects from the USB port that were increasing in frequency. This was audibly clear as the Windows USB event sounds announced this.
>  
>   I nearly burned my hand as I went to examine the drive and had to use BBQ gloves to turn it by the hot metal sides. I am no wimp but I could not keep my bare fingers on the drive long enough to turn it without pain.
>   If it is too hot to touch I figure that is just too hot... period.
>   Even though the USB plug was fully inserted, I noticed that the outlet was actually sagging in the flimsy plastic rear panel of the drive. Even taping the plug firmly into the outlet with duct tape did not help.
>   Even though I have owned and been pleased with 3 prior Iomega drives, it seems this model has definite design shortcomings.
>  
>   I have returned the drive to Iomega under the 1 year warranty for replacement, but I am ready to try another brand.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. So it seems I should do the same and return it to Iomega.

Comment: Yes i would suggest it, this model was just a poor make