# Drop in connection with Iomega iConnect drives

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, nas

I have an  Iomega iConnect connected to my home network via the router (hard wired). I have fibre optic 50Mb broadband at home.

The iConnect has 3 portable hard drives of various sizes connected via USB.

I keep on losing connection to the device while using both my desktop PC and laptop (both using Windows 7).

This is very frustrating as I am very enthusiastic about the iConnect technology as it is a very cheap way to run a pseudo NAS server.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be related:

http://superuser.com/questions/86031/external-iomega-desktop-usb-hard-drive-disconnects-while-in-use/86081#86081